# Why use hashes instead of test true equality?

Tags: python, dictionary, hash

I've recently been looking into Python's dictionaries (I believe they're called associate arrays in other languages) and was confused by a couple of the restrictions on its keys.

First, dict keys must be immutable. When I looked up the logic behind it the answer was that dictionaries work like hash tables to look up the values for keys, and thus immutable keys (if they're hashable at all) may change their hash value, causing problems when retrieving the value.

I understood why that was the case just fine, but I was still somewhat confused by what the point of using a hash table would be. If you simply didn't hash the keys and tested for true equality (assuming indentically constructed objects compare equal), you could replicate most of the functionality of the dictionary without that limitation just by using two lists.

So, I suppose that's my real question - what's the rationale behind using hashes to look up values instead of equality?

If I had to guess, it's likely simply because comparing integers is incredibly fast and optimized, whereas comparing instances of other classes may not be.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi O(n log n)?? how did you get that? EVEN FOR R/B tree, item access is only O(log n), whats the point of using hash map if it has a time complexity of O(n log n)

Comment: @JoeC, from memory :) I'm probably wrong here, I'm searching around to double-check. *My bad, the worst case I can find is O(log n / log log n). I stand corrected.*

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi also, O(n) is better than O(n log n) => list is faster than hash tables from what you have said :)

Comment: @JoeC, yup, you're right, I wonder where I was getting that complexity from. It looks like I was confusing with sorting complexity... Anyway, now I won't make the same mistake again :)

Answer (score 9):

You seem to be missing the whole point of a hash table, which is fast (O(1))<sup>1</sup> retrieval, and which cannot be implemented without hashing, i.e. transformation of the key into some kind of well-distributed integer that is used as an index into a table. Notice that equality is still needed on retrieval to be able to handle hash collisions<sup>2</sup>, but you resort to it only when you already narrowed down the set of elements to those having a certain hash.

With just equality you could replicate similar functionality with parallel arrays or something similar, but that would make retrieval O(n)<sup>3</sup>; if you ask for strict weak ordering, instead, you can implement RB trees, that allow for O(log n) retrieval. But O(1) requires hashing.

Have a look at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) for some more insight on hash tables.

---

*Notes*

1. It can become  O(n) in pathological scenarios (where all the elements get put in the same bucket), but that's not supposed to happen with a good hashing function.
2. Since different elements may have the same hash, after getting to the bucket corresponding to the hash you must check if you are actually retrieving the element associated with the given key.
3. Or O(log n) if you keep your arrays sorted, but that complicates insertion, which becomes on average O(n) due to shifting elements around; but then again, if you have ordering you probably want an RB tree or a heap.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi: more or less; you can get to O(n) in some pathological cases (all the elements get the same hash), but that's like the worst case of quicksort - it's not expected to happen in practice.

Comment: RB retrieval is `O(log(n))` instead of `O(n*log(n))` .... otherwise it would be worse than linear search.

Comment: It's O(1) average even with collisions. That is, with a well-distributed hash, you will get some average number of collisions per access, say 1. Sometimes you get 1 collision, sometimes 2, sometimes 0, sometimes even 5 but very rarely. So on average you need 2 tries to access anything (1 collision, 1 retry). It's O(2). O(2) is the same as O(1): O-notation ignores constant factors.

Answer (score 1):

By using hastables you achieve `O(1)` retrieval data, while comparing against each independent vale for equality will take `O(n)` (in a sequential search) or  `O(log(n))` in a binary search.

Also note that `O(1)` is amortized time, because if there are several values that hash to the same key, then a sequential search is needed among these values.